# Create a listener for a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm creating a jQuery application where a user can draw on a canvas. I need to add the functionality to dynamically enable a hyperlink when a certain percentage of the canvas has been drawn.

My program can detect what percentage of the canvas has been drawn on. Now, all I need is a way to create/enable a hyperlink on the canvas so that when the user clicks on it, he is redirected to the hyperlink URL.

I googled a way to do this, but couldn't find a good solution/explanation on how to go about doing this.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Inside the listener, check the percentage and `return false;` if the percentage doesn't meet your limit.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault).

```
function disableLink(e){e.preventDefault()};
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", disableLink)
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("a").removeEventListener("click", disableLink)
})
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddosg6yh/) to play with.